# Security updates: internet data daily quota

Tags: updates, security, xdelta

I would like to set a daily internet data quota for auto installing security updates.
Having the preference for smaller packages deps tree (all packages that depend on each other in a tree will be the total size to determine the winner).
And, set a few packages to always allow updating therefore having priority on the daily quota.

`update-manager` is python (that I dont know how to code/patch).
To create my own updater in bash would be a lot of trouble, so I prefer to continue doing it manually.

can we do it in some way, or is it too complex going beyond the setup of configuration files and command parameters?

any reason they do not use **XDelta** other than the complexity of implement such update methodology?

if in the end, the final answer is "it is impossible right now by any means", where can I suggest such improvement?

PS.: by "any means" I even mean a firewall quota (it is possible right?) to download from the server. But the problem would still be the priority and possibly incomplete packages in the end...

PS.2: once, I am quite sure, selecting packages manually may hiddenly auto select dependencies that may be quite big. Such deps should be auto selected on the list (the moment we click on such packages) so we could confirm what to install (so we would know how much will be downloaded and how long we can wait it end).

Comment: This sounds like a bug report or feature request with rather broad underlying question***s*** (plural!). The former is considered off topic since one should [report those on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.com/) and the latter is unsuitable for the Q&A format of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DavidFoerster mmm.. yes, it would be so unnecessarily complex that indeed it is certainly (mainly) a feature request. I found this email ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com , I will try it there, thx!

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to security patches, remember that a security patch means your system is broken and, although you might not have been attacked, you could be. I'd suggest that you install them all each time. I'm a retired unix and network security consultant for a major computer company and I always cringed when customers didn't want to install security patches ASAP. You read about them every day in the news. They have such a high chance of being the next "I've been hacked!" victim. And NEVER think, when it comes to security, that "If it ain't broke, don't fix it". It is broke. You may find how broke in a few minutes.

Comment: I understand, that's why I manually update all the small packages they provide promptly. But many have quite high size like >50MB, and sometimes such big file updates are made available 2 or even 3 times in a week, what is excellent to have them available so fast, but I wonder if they could use XDelta to make the download less cumbersome? A way to be 99% safe would be to not use such big applications as soon I see an update available, but... if they were using XDelta, I could update right away without caring so much for my internet data usage :/